# Interaction between two Spinner in Android custom form

Tags: android, forms, validation, spinner

I am developing my first Android app, and I want to make my `Spinner`s to interact. 
This means that I have a set of unique dates as `Gregorian Calendar` objects, but some of these share the same day and different hours, for example:

```
Mon, 6 July 2015  14:30
Mon, 13 July 2015  14:30
Mon, 13 July 2015  17:00
```

up until now the 2 spinners, one for the date and the other for the time, are completely indipendent:

[image]

but I want a configuration where as I select the first `Date` `Mon, 6 July 2015` I get to only choose 14:30 and when I select `Mon, 13 July 2015` I get to choose the two times `14:30` and `17:00`.

I know this is an easy task in `Javascript`, what about Java and Android?

Comment: Also you can do that. What exactly the question?

Comment: I want to make the second spinner to behave according to the first one, and viceversa

Comment: Repetitive spinner content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. It almost done for me to help you.

- Make two Spinners.
- After that setOnItemSelectedListener's to both.
- make Two methods - `filterOne(int selectedId)`, `filterTwo(int selectedId)`.

pseudo code :

```
Spinner first,second;
SpinnerAdapter firstAdapter, secondAdapter;

filterOne(int id) {
    secondAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(id);
    second.setAdapter(secondAdapter);
}

filerTwo(int id) {
    firstAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(id);
    first.setAdapter(firstAdapter);
}

ArrayList<Date> dates;
CustomSpinnerAdapter(int id) {
    dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    // on click from first spinner. set data to second.
    if(id == 0)  {
        dates.add(new Date(2015, 06, 10));
        dates.add(new Date(2015, 06, 11));
    } else if(id == 1) {
    // on click from second spinner. set data to first.
        dates.add(new Date(2015, 06, 10));
    }
}
```